# probability Indicator random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

The problem comes from the Cormen's Introduction to Algorithms, chapter 5: Probabilistic Analysis and Randomized Algorithms. More specifically It is from the 5.4.4 The online hiring problem.

Here n is the number of candidate and k= interviewing or rejecting 1st k number of candidate.

Pseudo code for ONLINE- MAXIMUM

```
ONLINE- MAXIMUM (k,n)

bestscore  = -infinty
for i = 1 to k
    if score(i)  > bestscore
         bestscore = score(i) 
for i = k + 1 to n
    if score(i) > bestscore
        return i
return n
```

I am wondering how could I solve it?

Comment: Where is the randomness?  Should we assume something about the order in which candidates arrive?

Comment: One reasonable assumption reduces this to the well-studied [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $i\in \{1,\dots,n-k-1\}$, there will be exactly $k+i$ interviews if and only if candidate $k+i$ is better than all previous candidates, and if the best candidate among the first $k+i-1$ candidates was one of the first $k$ candidates. The probability of both of these happening is
$$
\frac{k}{k+i-1}\times \frac{1}{k+i}
$$
The first fraction is the probability that the best candidate among $1,2,\dots,k+i-1$ occurs in the first $k$ candidates. The second fraction is the probability candidate $k+i$ is better than everyone before.

The last candidate is a special case. There will be exactly $n$ interviews if and only if the best of the previous candidates occurs in $\{1,\dots,k\}$, regardless of whether candidate $n$ was the best. The probability of this is just $\frac{k}{n-1}$.

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
E[\text{# interviews}]
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}(k+i)\cdot P(\text{# interviews }=k+i)
\\&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-k-1}(k+i)\times \frac{k}{k+i-1}\times \frac{1}{k+i}\right)+{n}\times \frac{k}{n-1}
\\&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}\frac{k}{k+i-1}\right)+k\cdot \frac{n}{n-1}
\\&=k\left(\frac1k +\frac1{k+1}+\dots+\frac1{n-1}+\frac{n}{n-1}\right)
\\&\approx k\Big(\log n-\log k + 1\Big)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate the 2nd line of the equation?